# Separate one column to two by row's value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - posts and meta

posts structure:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id    |  title  |
+---------+---------+
```

meta structure:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|   post  |   key   |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need to select records where meta.key is "end" or "result", and goup by post.id (if there's both "end" and "result" meta keys)

Here's my try:

```
SELECT
posts.id,
posts.title,
meta.post,
meta.`value`,
CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'result' THEN value END AS 'result',
CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'end' THEN value END AS 'end'
FROM
posts
INNER JOIN meta ON posts.id = meta.post
WHERE meta.`key` IN ('result', 'end')
```

It returns two separate records one with meta.key "end" and one with "result".

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    id      |   title    |   post     |   value    |   result   |     end    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1      |  Untitled  |      1     |     5      |    (Null)  | 1344240000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1      |  Untitled  |      1     |   88:79    |    88:79   |   (Null)   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I need is to merge those two records to one:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    id      |   title    |   post     |   value    |   result   |     end    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1      |  Untitled  |      1     |     -      |    88:79   | 1344240000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How do you propose to "merge" the value for the `value` field or is this field not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by INNER JOINing meta twice, i.e.

```
SELECT

  p.id,
  p.title,
  mr.value AS result,
  me.value AS end

FROM posts AS p

INNER JOIN meta AS mr

  ON mr.post = p.id
  AND mr.`key` = 'result'

INNER JOIN meta AS me
  ON me.post = p.id
  AND me.`key` = 'end';
```

SQL fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a89e/5

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to *pivot* the data, you would typically use an aggregate function with the `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  posts.id,
  posts.title,
  -- meta.post,
  -- meta.`value`,
  max(CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'result' THEN value END) AS 'result',
  max(CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'end' THEN value END) AS 'end'
FROM posts
INNER JOIN meta 
  ON posts.id = meta.post
WHERE meta.`key` IN ('result', 'end')
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.title  -- , meta.post, meta.`value`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65528/1)

Note:  You are showing two separate values for the `value` column, you will need to decide the logic to select a value because if those are distinct when the `group by` is performed you will get multiple rows.  So you will see that I commented out those two columns since they are being used in the `CASE` and the `post` column is already displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there's only one row for 'result' and one for 'end' per post id, you can just use `MAX` as an aggregate function with your original query and group by posts.id at the end; I can't quite figure out your logic for `VALUE` so I left it out for now;

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title,
  MAX(CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'result' THEN value END) AS 'result',
  MAX(CASE meta.`key` WHEN 'end' THEN value END)  AS 'end'
FROM posts
INNER JOIN meta ON posts.id = meta.post
WHERE meta.`key` IN ('result', 'end')
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.title
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27142/1).